Is Managed identity authentication possible in DocumentClient class from namespace Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client
My team uses below snippet to initialize DocumentClient object, for security reasons we need to use user assigned managed identity for authentication instead of access key authentication. is that allowed in DocumentClient class? if possible, how to achieve it? else, how to proceed further ?
 DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endPointURL), authKey);


you need to use a newer SDK: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3
